# Pandas dataframe from series of series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series of series, like so:

```
series_list = [pd.Series([1,2], index = ['A', 'B']), pd.Series([3,4], index = ['A', 'B'])]
data = pd.Series(series_list, index = ['i', 'ii'])
```

I would like to turn this data into a dataframe, using one index as the dataframe's column index, the other as the row index:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,3], 'B': [2,4]}, index = ['i', 'ii'])
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strict approach works fine:

```
pd.DataFrame(series_list,index = ['i', 'ii'])
```

Comment: Thanks... for `data` this translates into `pd.DataFrame(list(data), index = data.index)`.

Comment: Please, add explanation to your answer.